# Solution to move way from main thread in Service?

Tags: android, multithreading, service

**What should be used in service to move away from UI thread?**

For both Started Service and Bound Service

1. Loader
2. Asynctask
3. Simple thread
4. Robospice Library
5. Or something else

I want my service to keep on running even if the app is in background.

I want service to run indefinite time.

**Thanks.**

Comment: 6) [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) this depends on what you're doing. Use what works for your needs.

Comment: Subclass `Service` and start a background `Thread` there

Comment: ... also you should remeber about wakelocks ...

Comment: @Blackbelt  Thanks. What difference would be your solution from using IntentService.

Answer (score 0):

Use IntentService. It is a subclass of Service. It automatically runs the code in the background thread. And it clears itself up after the execution completes. You don't have to stop the IntentService.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to run single long task and stop service after that, you should use IntentService - it run on separate thred and stop itself after job is done. From your descriptin it seen like you want Service running indefinite time. For that you should use RxJava library. It has many advantages for performing concurrent operations, see docs for more details, among those;
Eas two thread pools and scheduler for main thread;
 Easily allow synchronizing concurret tasks - you can execute one task, wait for another, etc. without using pure java's locks. 
You can run job on one thread, then process results on another thread, etc;
You can process results in reactive ways;
You can create your own scheduler from HandlerThread and use single thread for all your tasks

Comment: Thanks. Yes I want my service to run indefinite time. Can you please leads me to some good links. Because I have no idea of RxJava and I also do not know if this is the best way to move away from main thread in service.